# function for finding if x is a multiple of y

Tags: clojure

Look at the function below. I want to pass a vector of factors and test if any of the elements in the vector is a factor of `x`. How do I do that?

```
(defn multiple?
  "Takes a seq of factors, and returns true if x is multiple of any factor."
  ([x & factors] (for [e m] ))
  ([x factor] (= 0 (rem x factor))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using [`some`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/some) and [`map`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/map):

```
(defn multiple? [x & factors]
  (some zero? (map #(rem x %) factors)))
```

Also `some` returns `nil` if all tests fail, if you need it to actually return `false`, you could put a [`true?`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/true_q) in there:

```
(defn multiple? [x & factors]
  (true? (some zero? (map #(rem x %) factors))))
```

---

Note that `some` short-circuits and `map` is lazy, so `multiple?` stops as soon as a match is found. e.g. the following code tests against the sequence `1,2,3,4,...`.

```
=> (apply multiple? 10 (map inc (range)))
true
```

Obviously this computation can only terminate if `multiple?` doesn't test against every number in the sequence.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve it only using `some`.

```
=> (defn multiple? [x factors]
 (some #(zero? (rem x %)) factors))
#'user/multiple?
=> (= true (multiple? 10 [3 4]))
false
=> (= true (multiple? 10 [3 4 5 6]))
true
```

`some` will stop at the first factor.

Comment: Ah, it's impolite to post an answer that is identical to another answer, especially as your answer is more than 20 minutes later than the original answer.

Comment: @dbaupp I don't think my answer is identical to yours. This one uses only `some`. Yours uses `some` and `map`.

Comment: Ah, I missed that. My apologies. :) (Also, `true?` is a neater way to write `= true`)

Comment: You are right. I think I picked up `= true` habit from [link](http://www.4clojure.com). :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, using explicit tail recursion:

```
(defn multiple? [x factors]
  "if any of the elements in the vector is a factor of x"
  (loop [factors factors]
        (cond (empty? factors) false
              (zero?  (rem x (first factors))) true
              :else   (recur (rest factors)))))
```

The advantages of the above solution include: it will stop as soon as it finds if any of the elements in the vector is a factor of `x`, without iterating over the whole vector; it's efficient and runs in constant space thanks to the use of tail recursion; and it returns directly a boolean result, no need to consider the case of returning `nil`. Use it like this:

```
(multiple? 10 [3 4])
=> false

(multiple? 10 [3 4 5 6])
=> true
```

If you want to obviate the need to explicitly pass a vector (for calling the procedure like this: `(multiple? 10 3 4 5 6)`)) then simply add a `&` to the parameter list, just like it was in the question.

Comment: The `map`/`some` solution exhibits the same behaviour. (It doesn't test every number in the sequence.)

Answer (score 0):

A more *Clojurian* way is to write a more general-purpose function: instead of answering true/false question it would return all factors of `x`. And because sequences are lazy it is almost as efficient if you want to find out if it's empty or not.

```
(defn factors [x & fs]
  (for [f fs :when (zero? (rem x f))] f))

(factors 5 2 3 4)
=> ()

(factors 6 2 3 4) 
=> (2 3)
```

then you can answer your original question by simply using `empty?`:

```
(empty? (factors 5 2 3 4))
=> true

(empty? (factors 6 2 3 4))
=> false
```

Comment: Using `filter` is more idiomatic than `for`: `(filter #(zero? (rem x %)) fs)`

Comment: Good comment, I agree. I've used `for` because @murtaza52 was trying to use it in the question itself.